# finding series representation with constant in numerator

Tags: sequences-and-series

how is the method for finding series rep when you have constant in numerator (and variable)

couldnt find anything when searching or in my mathbook

question: express (3+x)/(1+x) in terms of (x-1)^k

i know that you are supposed to get the expression in a form of a/(1-r), but now i have "r" also in numerator

Help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{x+3}{x+1}=1+\frac{2}{x+1}=1+\frac{2}{2+x-1}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{(x-1)}{2}}$$

Then by the geometric series you have

$$\frac{x+3}{x+1}=1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\frac{x-1}{2})^{n}$$

which converges when $|x-1|<2$.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{3+x}{1+x}=1+\frac2{2+(x-1)}.$$